How do I access google maps after dynamically loading multiple libraries at once?
I can dynamically load a google map library like this.
let map: google.maps.Map;

const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps") as google.maps.MapsLibrary;
map = new Map(document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement, {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
});

Now I want to load 2 libraries at once with this code below but I'm not familiar with this syntax and don't know how to create a new map or marker this way.
const [mapsLibrary, markerLibrary] = await Promise.all([
  google.maps.importLibrary("maps"),
  google.maps.importLibrary("marker")
]);


const { Map } = mapsLibrary; is one way.

oh I see. Thanks! If I wanted to make the importLibrary call in the constructor or in ngOnInit() so that I can call maps and marker later on in the component, how would I do that? How would I set the variables?  Ex. How would I declare const { Marker } above the constructor so that I can use it throughout my component

I'm not personally very familiar with Angular, but in a class you can just save things to instance variables in the constructor, eg this.map = mapsLibrary.Map and so on.
